# Automapper from list of object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have View Model and Class that I have to map.
This is my maping setting:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModels.objTest, clsTest>().ReverseMap();
```

I have to map List of View model to my `clsTest`.

for now I'm using looping like this:

```cs
List<clsTest> objListResult = new List<clsTest>();
if (List<objTest> != null)
{
    foreach (var item in objTest)
    {
        objListResult.Add(Mapper.Map<objTest, clsTest>(item));
    }
}
```

Its work fine, but is there anyway to map faster than this? Maybe is there any way mapping from List to List even my setting like above?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call Map with the list...

```
List<objTest> objListResult = Mapper.Map<List<clsTest>, List<objTest>>(objTest);
```

As you can see in documentation: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays

Comment: this is the answer I really need!! thank you for giving me the answer!